# Unable to remove malware

Tags: malware

I downloaded MalwareBytes from their website and ran it twice I think. What other malware scanners are out there?

I suspect it is malware because I keep my laptop super clean, i scan every week using malwarebytes, avira and spybot. All of a sudden my web browser has begun showing me "deals" at the top of the page and it pops up with "better prices" whenever I go to online shops. Now my computer has been acting laggy and weird, also when I turned on the machine today it had to do a disk check and repair a file which I was not readily aware of. (it had to repair something deep inside the directories).

To further my suspicions, this is the first time I was ever prompted to do a disk check on this machine. Just bought it about 6 months ago and once i got this strange toolbar on my computer WITHOUT MY CONSENT now I'm having issues with Chrome crashing and my computer doing checks on itself, luckily it has certain self-repair systems in place but I don't want to have to run these all the time or risk serious damage to my laptop.

Comment: It sounds like you should clean your browser profiles, to see, if the behavior you describe helps.  We won't be recommending software to you though here at Superuser.  Question seeking software recommendations are specifically not within the scope of Superuser

Answer (score 0):

I use to face the same pop ups issue

1. Go to Google chrome extensions > disable and delete the extensions, which you feel suspicious.(before deleting them just make a note of the extension source, details...)
2. Then go to control panel and try to search for the same software of extension which might have been installed try to uninstall them.

Try the above it worked for me.

And also install any add-blocking extension from the browser.( If not done already)

Comment: it doesnt pop up in the extensions menu so im pretty sure this is malicious software since i does not identify itself in the proper format

Comment: @Daniel try this [https://superuser.com/questions/100360/how-can-i-remove-malicious-spyware-malware-adware-viruses-trojans-or-rootkit] as others pointed out.